# How come and when is it possible to use shorter method signatures in Swift?

Tags: swift

How come and when is it possible to use shorter method signatures in Swift even though they are not present in the official Apple Docs?

For example:

```
let workerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.worker", attributes: .concurrent)
```

When I browse the documentation the only methods I see are these:

```
func async(group: DispatchGroup?, qos: DispatchQoS, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags, execute: () -> Void)
```

and

```
func asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime, execute: DispatchWorkItem)
```

So how and why is this possible:

```
workerQueue.asynch(group: slowAddGroup) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Please read the section *Trailing Closures* in [Swift Language Guide: Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) and *Default Parameter Values* in [Swift Language Guide: Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158)

Comment: I have found it and read it. You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function. This is exactly what puzzled me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That particular shorthand is possible for two reasons: default values for input parameters and trailing closures.
Have a look at the actual type signature for the function:

`func async(group: DispatchGroup? = default, qos: DispatchQoS = default, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags = default, execute work: @escaping () -> Void)`

You can clearly see that all input parameters have default values except for the closure. If you omit any of these, the compiler will use the default value.

Since `work` is a closure, which is the last input parameter to the function, as a shorthand notation, you can move it outside the parentheses and just write it after the function call, which is called a [trailing closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Answer (score 1):

default parametrers set to default values... See for yourself, declare function

```
func doSomething(withThis this: Any, andOptional optional: Any? = nil) {
// Do smth incredible
}
```

now try autocompletion on your own, it should complete you with 2 functions even you declared one... Thats because you set in the function declaration default parameter value :)

Answer (score 1):

The actual method signature is:

```
public func async(group: DispatchGroup? = default, qos: DispatchQoS = default, flags: DispatchWorkItemFlags = default, execute work: @escaping @convention(block) () -> Swift.Void)
```

All the `=` assignments are default values.  As a result, you are specifying the group and leaving all the others as `default`.